# How to run powershell CheckNetIsolation command in batch file

Tags: powershell, command-line

I need to run the following Powershell command as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/error-messages/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost from the command line:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="microsoft.win32webviewhost_cw5n1h2txyewy"
```

Although it works on the PowerShell, it doesn't on the commandline. This is a command I tried:

```
powershell.exe -command "& {CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=microsoft.win32webviewhost_cw5n1h2txyewy}"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The powershell command mentioned in the link is not a powershell specific command. It can be run as it is on the regular DOS commandline as long as DOS box was run as administrator.